# python how to provide a function to be called to others

Tags: python, function, call

I have write 3 def to use it but I cant be called to other function from my teammate.

```
def readciscodevice(function, device):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        if device == "switch":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read
        elif device == "router":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;
        elif device == "showcommand":
            cur.execute(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM showcommand WHERE   function =? or  function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                    (function,))
            read = cur.fetchall()
            return read;


    def get_input():
    a = input("function and params (comma separated):")
    b = input("device:")
    pattern = re.compile('\(.*?\)')

    output_commands = []

    params = a.split(',')

    function = params[0]

    print (params)

    counter = 1
    for result in readciscodevice(function,b):
        command = result[0]
        found_parentheses_list = re.findall(pattern, command)

        output_command = command



        for i, param_placeholder in enumerate(found_parentheses_list):

            param = params[counter]
            output_command = re.sub(pattern, param, output_command, count=1)
            counter +=1
        output_commands.append(output_command)
    # input_para(a,b)
    return output_commands

# def input_para(a,b):
#     print(a,b)
# other program calls:

commands = get_input()

for command in commands:
    #do sth, print for example
    print(command)
```

If I input function and paraneter like:
fa ip,0,1,192.168.0.1,255.255.255.0
and it prints out

```
['fa ip', '0', '1', '192.168.0.1', '255.255.255.0']
enable
configure terminal
interface fa0/1
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
```

But I cannot return my function to other teammate, it seems the basic call function problem, could anyone explain about it ?

Comment: Can you show the actual code and invocation? Its hard to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: What do you mean by "returning the function to other teammate?"

Comment: @fdsa As I do not know what his program structure.But it may not be a problem that we need to concern

Comment: @TommyChan Could you write an example of what you would like him to be able to do? It is difficult to understand what your problem is.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes I have done it

Comment: @fdsa I would like him to receive commands and sends command to the cisco device

Comment: Do you want to send the plain-text function? @TommyChan

Comment: @zachgates7 Yes just return it and string type

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send the function as plain-text, you can do something like this.

```
myTestFunction = """
def myTestFunction():
    print('This is a test!')
"""
```

Defining the function as a string. You can then pass it as an argument.

Comment: what should I input in myTestFunction = ?

Comment: `myTestFunction` is a string. @TommyChan